# Why must a function be independent of coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

What is the motivation for why a function should be independent of coordinates?

In the case of a general manifold I kind of get why, since one (usually) defines a function $f$ as a map from the manifold to the reals, i.e. $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and so in this sense it is manifestly coordinate independent (since $f$ has been defined without introducing any particular coordinate system). However, is there a reason in general (both heuristically and technically) why a function should be coordinate independent? In physics, the standard argument seems to be that a function is a scalar and so has no directional dependence, thus it should be invariant under rotations of coordinate systems. However, I'm unsure how this extends in generality (for example, why should it be true for a coordinate translation. Is it simply that coordinates are an artefact of the observer and so the value of the scalar function should not depend on the coordinates chosen, much like a vector is coordinate independent and this requires that its individual components should transform under coordinate transformations)?

I'm fairly new to the concept of differential geometry so I apologise for such a basic question, but hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: in differential geometry, you want the differential operators ($f \mapsto T[f](p)$) to be linear in $f$ and independent of the choice of coordinates

Comment: Heuristically, I think this is the idea: there are certain properties of a function that become more obvious with the right coordinate system. The more you can say about a function in terms that are independent to the choice of coordinate system, the easier it becomes to find the most suitable choice.

Comment: Also, the coordinate-independent properties of a function are how you derive the way coordinate changes should work (i.e. co/contravariance)

Comment: In physics coordinate independence is a consequence of the [principle of general invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_covariance).  That is, it wouldn't make sense for the underlying physical laws to depend on which coordinate system *we choose*, so the mathematical functions describing those laws must not depend on coordinates, either.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   So is a function simply defined to be coordinate independent then? With vectors, I can understand that heuristically the components must change under coordinate transformations, since a given vector has a direction associated with it and this is an intrinsic property, i.e. it doesn't depend on the observer (coordinate system), as such its components must change under a coordinate transformations (in this sense, vector components are not scalars)....

Comment: ... Furthermore, components of a vector a defined with respect to a given basis, usually chosen to be the coordinate basis induced by the particular coordinate system, so it makes sense rom this perspective that they should change under a change in coordinates.

Comment: @Bye_World     I get that physics should be independent of observer (in other words, of any given coordinate system), but how does one then demand that functions are invariant under coordinate transformations, whereas vectors (or rather, vector components) transform? (Is what I put in the case of vectors in my comment above this one correct reasoning at all?)

Comment: I would say that any such function *could* be defined without any coordinate system; that is, the function depends only on intrinsic properties of the manifold. This function is an object that exists without a coordinate system just as the Manifold exists without a coordinate system. Ultimately, a function is a rule that takes a point on the manifold $M$ and produces a real number. That being said, the most reasonable way to *specify points in $M$* is via a coordinate system. For this reason, one often selects a coordinate system in order to describe a function.

Comment: @user35305 As you say vector *components* transform under passive transformations, not the vectors themselves.  Basic example: $\vec F = m\vec a$ is a completely coordinate independent statement -- it holds regardless of the coordinate system we choose.  But of course once a coordinate system is chosen, the components of the two vector quantities would change under a coordinate transformation.  So this provides an example of a covariant equation and a noncovariant equation.  $\vec F=m\vec a$ is covariant (doesn't change under coordinate transforms) and $F_x = mv_x$ is **not** covariant.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   So essentially, is the point that one wishes to define objects that are dependent on the intrinsic properties of the manifold, and not on any particular coordinate system, since the latter wouldn't be particularly useful, they wouldn't be well defined quantities since their value would depend on which coordinate system we choose (which is an essentially arbitrary choice)? Also, would my comments on vectors be correct at all?

Comment: @Bye_World     So is the idea that objects that are not covariant are not well defined since they depend on our arbitrary choice of coordinate system, and thus not useful (particularly for describing physical phenomena)?! Also, is what I said for the reason why vector components transform be correct at all?

Comment: Covariant equations correspond physically to statements which are frame independent.  Noncovariant equations describe frame dependent phenomena.

Comment: So, for example, would inertial forces (such as centrifugal force) be described by non covariant equations?

Comment: Exactly.  All "fictitous forces" are frame dependent and thus the mathematical statements describing them must be noncovariant.

Comment: @Bye_World     So all real physical phenomena should be coordinate independent and thus be described by covariant equations then?! Also, sorry to bug you about this (just want to make sure I've understood the intuition correctly), but is the reasoning I put in my previous comments for why vector components transform under changes in coordinates be correct at all?

Comment: Yes.  The components of vectors change in the opposite way that the coordinates change so that the vectors themselves stay the same under coordinate transforms.  Wikipedia has [an article on the $M=\Bbb R^n$ case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).

Comment: @Bye_World     But is the intuitive argument for why the components of a vector must transform under coordinate transformations because a vector has a direction associated with it, which is an intrinsic property and thus coordinate independent. If its components didn't transform then its direction would become coordinate dependent, contradicting this fact. Furthermore, since the components of a vector are with respect to a given coordinate basis, one would naturally expect that when the basis changes the components will do to (since a vector exists indepently of any given basis)?!...

Comment: Yes.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: @Bye_World     ... In the case of **active** transformations, is it that the vector itself is actively "moved" around (not a coordinate dependent statement), and so in this case, the direction in which the vector points will change and will not be equal to the untransformed vector, right?!

Comment: @user35305 Right.  An example of an active transformation is the inertia tensor acting on the angular velocity to "move the vector" to coincide with the angular momentum.  This has no effect on the coordinate axes, only on the vector $\omega$ itself.

Comment: @Bye_World     Ok, thanks for your help. I think I understand it a bit better now. So, for functions, is the point that one should be able to rotate, translate, etc. your coordinate system, but the value of the function at a given point should be independent of the coordinate system that one chooses to label these points, since such a labelling is arbitrary? For example, in physics, one often demands that a scalar field satisfies $\phi'(x')=\phi(x)$. Is this basically the statement that although the coordinate representation of the function will look different with respect to the two...

Comment: ... systems, in that it will have the form $\phi(x)$ in the original coordinate system and $\phi'(x')$ in the new coordinate system, the value of the function in the old coordinate system evaluated at a coordinate $x$ is equal to the value of the function in the new coordinate system evaluated at the point $x'$ which is the mapping of the old coordinate into the new coordinate system, i.e. $x\mapsto x'$?!

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. I haven't read through the whole comment discussion but I'm finding it hard to understand the question. A function is a function. By itself it has nothing to do with coordinates. Its on the level of sets: you just have domain, codomain and function.

So choosing coordinates can't change a function; the coordinates are extraneous.

It's like defining an object A. Once it's defined its defined. And then saying "pick a number". Did the number somehow change the object!?

Comment: Maybe I'm just trying to find an issue that isn't there then. For some reason I can see why vector components should change with coordinate changes, since they are objects that exist independently of any given coordinate system and so coordinate transformations should not change intrinsic properties such as magnitude and direction, but I'm getting myself muddled with functions. I think it's because in physics, not much motivation is given for why (scalar) functions should be coordinate independent in general...

Comment: ... I get that they should be invariant under rotations of coordinate systems (since they have no directional dependence), but not why in general (surely a translation would change the value of the function, or is the point that we're talking about passive coordinate transformations and not active transformations on the manifold?!). Is the point that, given a function $\phi:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and two coordinate charts $\psi_{1}:U_{1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\psi_{2}:U_{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the function...

Comment: ... has two different coordinate representations, $\phi_{1}=\phi\circ\psi^{-1}_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}=\phi\circ\psi^{-1}_{2}$. Then, for a given point $p\in U_{1}\cap U_{2}$, there are two coordinate representations of the same point, $x=\psi_{1}(p)$ and $x'=\psi_{2}(p)$, and so we require that $\phi_{1}(x)=\phi_{2}(x')$. If we denote $\phi:=\phi_{1}$ and  $\phi':=\phi_{2}$ (apologies for the abuse of notation here), then the above requirement can be expressed as $\phi'(x')=\phi(x)$, which is the expression given in physics for the usual requirement of coordinate invariance of scalar fields...

Comment: ... Is this what is meant by a function be coordinate invariant?!